# Should an old question that fall into XY problem category get a title edit?

Tags: discussion

*If you don't know what an XY problem is, read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).*

Today, after researching my problem, I stumbled over [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351845/finding-the-type-of-an-object-in-c).

This question is an obvious example of "XY problem":

- the author was asking about Y: differentiating object types, as in the same thing as python's `isinstance()`,
- he thought it would solve his problem X: polimorphic dispatch type uncertainty,
- but what the people answering the question suggested, was that the
  actual resolution to it would be Z: using `dynamic_cast<>()`.

Because Google indexes Stack Overflow the way it does, the only legible and coherent thing I took out from what it had shown me about this question, was the title of it. And so, because of that, I predicted to learn something about RTTI and such. But I was left disappointed.

The question is: should such questions be edited, so that the title states what the reader could actually learn from the answers?

Comment: So what about future searches that think that `X` will solve their `Y'` problem? How will *they* find this question?

Comment: Which title would you propose? Keep in mind that we're talking about a highly viewed, highly voted question with lots of answers that should still be reasonably applicable after the edit.

Comment: @Tunaki Something like: "making sure that an object is of class X" maybe? I was kind of asking in a general sense, that question was just an example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not sure what you mean by "X will solve", since "X" is the problem in this case, not the solution. And I never really understood why would that be such a big deal anyway. If the information in the page doesn't fit the search query for which it appeared somewhere, then it means that it was wrongly indexed in the first place. Since SO can't change the way Google maps pages to queries, I think SO should optimize for it - editing questions that appear to fit somebody's search results, but actually have nothing to do with them, would be a good move IMO.